# Distance between points on a polar coordinate system

Tags: polar-coordinates, arc-length

Imagine a polar coordinate system with radius = 1. The line that connects these two coordinates is a spiral: (0,0) (10π,1).

How can the length of this spiral be calculated? (Points above are just samples for a "multi rotation" situation... But it can be any two points..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give a hint on how to setup the problem:

You can use the formula for the arc-length in polar coordinates.

$$ds=\sqrt{r^{2}+(\frac{dr}{dθ})^{2}}dθ$$

with $L=\int ds$.

With a standard spiral you have r to be a linear function of theta $r(\theta) = r_{0}+b(\theta - \theta_{0})$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm quite rusty with mathematics so please bear with me.. i have a few questions.. ds is the arc length.. r is the radius, but at what point? at the end? so in my case 1? and what are the other two? dr and dθ? thank you